# How the use the pre-trained model(.caffemodel file) provided in the below link?

Tags: caffe, pre-trained-model

https://github.com/playerkk/face-py-faster-rcnn

the link above has indicated that a pretrained model is available.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXxvu.png)

Comment: you can see a pre-trained model has been indicated in the bottom of the page. But I don't know how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After you download the pretrained weights ( a .`caffemodel` file), you can instantiate a caffe.Net object with the network definition (`.prototxt` file - from the repository you referred, [test.prototxt](https://github.com/playerkk/face-py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/models/face/VGG16/faster_rcnn_end2end/test.prototxt)), e.g.

```
net = caffe.Net(prototxt, caffemodel, caffe.TEST)
```

(I guess you would like to use the pretrained model for inference, if you would like to do transfer-learning on your data you should use `caffe.TRAIN`).

Then you should load the image, feed it into the input blobs, run `net.forward` on the image and extract the results from the output blobs - e.g. `net.blobs['cls_score'].data`, `net.blobs['cls_prob'].data` and `net.blobs['bbox_pred'].data`.

You can use the original py-faster-rcnn's [demo](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/demo.py) with minor adjustments.

Good luck!